# Problem with Indefinite Integral $\int \frac {\cos^5x}{ 16(\cos^4x+\sin^4x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Hello guys I'm totally lost in this indefinite integral, i'm just looking for advices/tips

$$\int \frac {\cos^5x}{ 16(\cos^4x+\sin^4x)}dx$$

Should I begin with universal substitution? or there is any other way to reduce the difficulty of this integral? As always thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean $sin^4x$?

Comment: In some countries, $\sen x$ means $\sin x$

Comment: I see, but according to Wolfram, this thing does not have a anti derivative in terms of elementary functions

Comment: Substitute $t=\sin x$ to get a rational function.

Comment: The integral is the same as the easier $$\int \frac{\cos^5(x)}{4\cos(4x)+12}$$

Comment: @cryo codex: what is universal substitution?

Comment: as far as I understand it since i'm just a regular student is a subtitution where you can go from trigonometric terms to algebraic terms where $z = tan(\frac x2) $ so $x = 2arctg(z)$ then $dx = \frac {2dz}{1+z^2}$ and then you can use these ones $senx = \frac {2z}{1+z^2}$ $cosx = \frac {1-z^2}{1+z^2} $ but for this exercise it shouldn't be route i should've thought of!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that all the trig functions in your integral have even powers, except for the cosine in the numerator. This tells us we can use the "extra" power of $\cos x$ with the $dx$ to get a good substitution. $\cos x\,dx$ is the differential of $\sin x$, so let's change all the other trig functions to sines.

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac {\cos^5x}{ 16(\cos^4x+\sin^4x)}\,dx &= \int \frac {(\cos^2 x)^2}{16[(\cos^2 x)^2+\sin^4x]}\cos x\,dx \\
 &= \int \frac {(1-\sin^2 x)^2}{16[(1-\sin^2 x)^2+\sin^4x]}\,d(\sin x) \\
 &= \int \frac {(1-u^2)^2}{16[(1-u^2)^2+u^4]}\,du
\end{align}$$

with $u=\sin x$. You now have a rational function in $u$ to integrate, which can be done by the usual means.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks man I really appreciate it i'm just starting to learn integration and I do know all the methods but when I see exercises like this I just get blocked easily thanks so much!

Comment: how to do by usual means? i am not really gettting you please explain how tto proceed further?

Comment: i think he's talking about the usual integration methods as partial fractions, substitution, integrate by parts, universal substitution, trigonometric substitution, those are the ones i just know at this moment

Comment: By "the usual means" of integrating "a rational function" I mean expanding out the powers, partial fractions, and integrating each fraction resulting from the partial fractions which uses completing the square trigonometric and other substitution, etc. Basically, partial fractions. You should know that technique well before tackling a problem like this one.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: this integral has an elemetary antiderivative and you can use the tan half angle substitution

Comment: Gotta be honest and say that I don't see it yet, any other tip? I do know the tan half angle formula but I don't see how it may help me in this one but thanks tho! i'm gonna try to think harder, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Notice,  $$\int \frac{\cos^5x}{16(\cos^4x+\sin^4x)}\ dx=\frac{1}{16}\int \frac{(1-\sin^2x)^2}{((1-\sin^2x)^2+\sin^4x)}\ (\cos x dx)$$
let $\sin x=t\implies \cos x\ dx=dt$,
$$=\frac{1}{16}\int\frac{(1-t^2)^2}{((1-t^2)^2+t^4)}\ dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\int\frac{t^4-2t^2+1}{2t^4-2t^2+1}\ dt$$

$$=\frac{1}{16}\int\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}-t^2}{2t^4-2t^2+1}\right)\ dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\left(\int \frac12 \ dt+\int\frac{\frac{1}{2t^2}-1}{2t^2-2+\frac{1}{t^2}}\ dt\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac t2-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)\left(\sqrt 2-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+(\sqrt 2-1)\left(\sqrt 2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{2t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}-2}\ dt\right)$$

$$=\frac{t}{32}-\frac{1}{64}\int \frac{(\sqrt 2+1)\left(\sqrt 2-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{2t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}-2}\ dt-\frac{1}{64}\int \frac{(\sqrt 2-1)\left(\sqrt 2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{2t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}-2}\ dt$$

$$=\frac{t}{32}-\frac{\sqrt 2+1}{64}\int \frac{\left(\sqrt 2-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt}{\left(\sqrt 2t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-2(\sqrt 2+1)}-\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{64}\int \frac{\left(\sqrt 2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt}{\left(\sqrt 2t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+2(\sqrt 2-1)}$$

$$=\frac{t}{32}-\frac{\sqrt 2+1}{64}\int \frac{d\left(\sqrt 2t+\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(\sqrt 2t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2+1)}\right)^2}-\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{64}\int \frac{d\left(\sqrt 2t-\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(\sqrt 2t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2-1)}\right)^2}$$

$$=\frac{t}{32}-\frac{\sqrt 2+1}{64}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2+1)}}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt 2t+\frac{1}{t}-\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2+1)}}{\sqrt 2t+\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2+1)}}\right|-\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{64}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2-1)}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2t-\frac{1}{t}}{\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2-1)}}\right)+C $$

$$=\color{red}{\frac{t}{32}-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt 2+1}}{128\sqrt 2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt 2t+\frac{1}{t}-\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2+1)}}{\sqrt 2t+\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2+1)}}\right|-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt 2-1}}{64\sqrt 2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2t-\frac{1}{t}}{\sqrt{2(\sqrt 2-1)}}\right)+C }$$

Comment: Oh wow man I hope I didn't take too much of your time that's amazing! I'm just starting to learn integration and well this one is complicated for me but I got what you did with that substitution! thank you so much